# Angular ui routing and permissions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, security, angular-ui-router

I am currently using `ui.router` for my page routing in my Angular application but it am starting to get a bit of issues with exploiting parts of my applications to users that don't have permissions to it.

I have tried to find documentation on this with no luck so fare so hope somebody in here have an approach for this.

In my example below i show that there are three pages in my application, but not all are allowed to go to the `moderators` page. If they do i will of course validate the permission server side and redirect them, but i feel that showing all possible pages in my application is a bit of exploiting it, can this in some way be limited with `ui.router`, and not by my auto generating the router file server side, or is that just something i need to live with :)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('default', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
        'mainViewContainer': {
            templateUrl: 'pages/default.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('news', {
        url: '/news',
        views: {
        'mainViewContainer': {
            templateUrl: 'pages/news.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('moderators', {
        url: '/moderators',
        views: {
        'mainViewContainer': {
            templateUrl: 'pages/moderators.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding using resolve - a list of things that are preconditions for a state.

```
.state(..., {
    ...
    resolve: {
         adminPermission: (AdminService) => {
               return AdminService.validate();
         }
    }
    ...
 })
```

Then, if `AdminService` returns a promise that fails, the app will not enter the state (and you can catch it using a `$onStateChangeError` event)

**Edit:**
How about writing the moderator state in an if clause i.e.

```
If(isAdmin) 
   stateProvider.state(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but that will still not prevent the route for being presented to a user that browse the javascript file downloaded to his machine. I would like to him not even being able to see that the page exists

Comment: If you don't want to generate a different config file, how about adding an if clause before registering the state?

Comment: i don't understand that about an if clause?

Comment: But it will still be visible if you access the javascript file the user downloaded? I am looking to see if the is a framework for not even make it visible in the javascript file when downloaded, so it should probably be handled server side before serving the file to the client

Comment: You should remember that angular is a client side framework, and even if it changed the actual file, the user could the original file in the network tab. If that is indeed what you need, you'll have to resort to a server side solution, although I don't see any reason that the resolve based solution wouldn't be good. If not, you probably separate your SPA into two different pages - a client app and a mod app

Comment: Yes, and it is the server side handling of the file i was hopping someone had a good idea for, if someone knew an existing framework for it. I can't separate my app, there is a very fine grand permission model, it is not just "user" / "admin"

Comment: You can send a different config file (only for the routing part) based on permissions. I don't know in which framework your server is written so I can't advise you any frameworks, but this seems simple enough to me